# Why does the last printf create new lines after each placeholder?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name [50];
    char age [50];

    printf("Please enter your name:\n");
    fgets(name, 20, stdin);

    printf("Please enter your age:\n");
    fgets(age, 20, stdin);

    printf("Hello %s, you are %s years old", name, age);

    return 0;
}
```

//sorry for such a trvial question I am new to programming, but Why does the last printf create new
lines after each placeholder?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting input from `stdin`, so you are probably ending your entries by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>: therefore you end your line with the `\n` character and `fgets()` stores it into the `name` and `age` variables.

Comment: Not ”probably”.  For all practical purposes, it's a certainty that the inputs are terminated with a newline which is causing the line breaks in the output.